# Rails: using a variable for creating a record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, controller

I have 4 different groups of data that I want to:
create, 
update, 
delete

I want to use one action for each function, using a variable, but can't get it to work.

For example:

```
def create

@type = params['type']   # use an outside ajax request to decide type
@type.create(:title => 'new title')  # create a new table using that type

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `constantize`?

```
def create
  @type = params['type'].constantize   # use an outside ajax request to decide type
  @type.create(:title => 'new title')  # create a new table using that type
end
```

Comment: @jakobk, remember to use a whitelist, you don't want a GlobalThermonuclearWar.create(...) ;-)